# Search and insert line-break inside XSL variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I have been messing with this for while now and I hope you guys can help.
So I have a XSL variable like

```
<xsl:variable name="blah" select="'texttexttext texttexttexttext Note:texttexttexttext'" />
```

What I'm trying to do is first search for "Note:" in $blah. If it is found, add a line break before it like `&#xD;` . So the output will be like

```
blah-> "'texttexttext texttexttexttext &#xD;Note:texttexttexttext'"
```

I'm able to search for the term using the usual contains function like:

```
<xsl:if test="(contains($blah,'Note:'))">true</xsl:if>
```

but I'm confused on getting replace/insert of line break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 2.0 comes with some nice regex functions.

By using the replace function as here :

```
replace($blah, "(.*)(Note:.*)", "$1&amp;#xD;$2")
```

You shall get the desired result. So basically, I am catching all before and after `Note:` and I am just putting your line-break in between at the result.